# In-place upgrade from Windows Server 2008 (Not R2) to 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Is it possible to perform an In-Place upgrade **straight from Server 2008** (Not R2) to 2012 R2?
I have read a number of pages but they all talk of upgrading from 2008 R2 to 2012 R2, not 2008 to 2012 R2..

Yet, while reading the Exam Ref 70-410 book, (Installing and configuring windows server 2012 R2), its talking of upgrading from Server 2008 or 2008 R2. its not specifying which release exactly the book is based upon...

Kindly help

Thanks

Comment: No, it isn't possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you took a peek at [the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn303416(v=ws.11).aspx) you would see that 2008 to 2012 R2 is not a supported upgrade path.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. I have been wondering, now i know this too